# Noun form of "controlling," as a personality characteristic

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that could be applied to a person who is controlling or overbearing. Either the name of a quality they possess (ie an impetuous person has recklessness), or something they could be said to be (ie an exceptionally nice person is an angel).

Nothing so strong as a despot, but "pusher" is a bit weak, as well. I've gone through dictionary.com's thesaurus for a bit, trying to related-word my way into a noun form of overbearing (without just tacking a -ness onto the end), but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence showing how the word you're looking for would be used?  (You can put _____ where the word would go.)  Are you ruling out all -ness words?

Comment: *control freak* works.

Comment: It would be in a list of words used to describe a character, so something like 'John is an angel, though possessed of recklessness, and slightly veering into licentiousness.' I don't like using so many -ness words, however. The "taskmaster" answer from Phil Sweet is a very good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Taskmaster**

> : one that imposes a task or burdens another with labor

"Taskmaster." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 22 Sept. 2018.

Idiomatically, it is often used to suggest excessive, and often heavy handed, bossiness. It is more often used in this derogatory sense than not.

Answer (score 2):

How about **dominator**?

Annoyingly, I can only find dictionary definitions for the verb *dominate*, although the noun should really be the same.

From Merriam-Webster, here are some example sentences that use [*dominate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominate):

> // a hill that dominates the town
>   // his desire to dominate
>   // He dominated her life for many years.

And Oxford has some example sentences with [**dominator**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dominator) itself:

> *‘As the imbalance of power between the two grows, the dominated girl is no longer recognized by her dominator as a subject.’*
>   *‘The two were well on their way to becoming dominators of the UK trance scene.’*
>   *‘It ought not be surprising at all, then, that whistleblowers get persecuted using all the insidious, ingenious, devious, and oppressive means dominators in our society can apply.’*